# Android How does PACKAGE_RESTARTED intent work?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am new to Android development.
I want to get a notice when the operating system (because of lack of memory) or other application (Task killer e.g. [ZDbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zdworks.android.toolbox)) restart other applicatoin (not mine).

I tried BroadcastReceiver. It did not get any Intent when an app was killed and the user started it manually. I have used `PACKAGE_RESTARTED` intent but `BroadcastReceiver` did not get any Intent.

Any suggestions?

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED);
    filter.addDataScheme("package"); 

    BroadcastReceiver pkgRemoveReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do my stuff              
        }
    };
registerReceiver(pkgRemoveReceiver, filter);
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be registering your broadcast receiver?

Comment: Thanks shoe rat. I forgot to add the line here. But in my code, yes I did!